# Right click with SendKeys in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, sendkeys

I am using sendkeys in C# .NET. I have letters, arrow keys and enter working. I cant figure out how to send a right click for the context menu. I know i can press a key on my keyboard to do it but i have no idea how to send the msg. How do i? i googled and saw

```
new MenuItem().PerformClick();
```

as a solution however i didnt see any affect. The keys are being sent to another application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the user32.dll, [I got the general idea from here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/transparentform_send_mouse_click_to_desktop.asp)

**EDIT:**
I added in posX and posY, which would be the mouse coordinates.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WinApi
{  
    public class Mouse
    { 
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags,UInt32 dx,UInt32 dy,UInt32 dwData,IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

            private const UInt32 MouseEventRightDown = 0x0008;
            private const UInt32 MouseEventRightUp = 0x0010;

            public static void SendRightClick(UInt32 posX, UInt32 posY)
            {
                mouse_event(MouseEventRightDown, posX, posY, 0, new System.IntPtr());
                mouse_event(MouseEventRightUp, posX, posY, 0, new System.IntPtr());
            }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to the key positioned a few places right of the spacebar, which performs the same operation as the right mouse button in some situations, **{MENU}** may be the special key you want to send.  It is not implemented in some SendKeys variations, and I am unsure of the latest version of C#.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send mouse input using the .NET `SendKeys` class. At least, not that I know of nor that's documented. The best way to do this is to switch to the WinAPI and use the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) method. You can use this in .NET using [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) for the function (in "user32.dll") and [`StructLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) for the structures.

Then you will want to call it like this:

```
INPUT pressRight;
pressRight.type = MOUSE; // = 0
pressRight.mi.dx = 0;
pressRight.mi.dy = 0;
pressRight.mi.mouseData = 0;
pressRight.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN; // = 8
pressRight.mi.time = 0;
pressRight.mi.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

INPUT releaseRight = pressRight;
releaseRight.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP; // = 10

INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[2];
inputs[0] = pressRight;
inputs[1] = releaseRight;

SendInput(2, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The {MENU} key is not always avialable, as noted by @Sparr. However, shift-F10 brings up the context menu in most Windows applications. So `SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}");` should work.