# Automating a ContextMenu with Watin

Tags: watin

I'm trying to automate an HTML Contextmenu that appears when I right click on an element. I'm using watin & IE 9.
I have already tried the following:

```
    NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection();
    props.Add("button", "2");
    tc.FireEvent("click", props);
    tc.FireEvent("mousedown", props);
    tc.FireEvent("mouseup", props);
```

I just keep getting an invalid argument exception for these.

Any other suggestions for getting the contextmenu or solving this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the right click through Interop?

eg [Right click with SendKeys in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024088/right-click-with-sendkeys-in-net)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WinApi
{  
    public class Mouse
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags,UInt32 dx,UInt32 dy,UInt32 dwData,IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        private const UInt32 MouseEventRightDown = 0x0008;
        private const UInt32 MouseEventRightUp = 0x0010;

        public static void SendRightClick(UInt32 posX, UInt32 posY)
        {
            mouse_event(MouseEventRightDown, posX, posY, 0, new System.IntPtr());
            mouse_event(MouseEventRightUp, posX, posY, 0, new System.IntPtr());
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: SendRightClick works fine but how to get the element x y coordinates with respect to screen using WatiN?